# php - Google Play Store API for Games

Tags: php, android, api, google-play

I am developing a website where I need to display all the games related to iOS, play store and windows store. I have acquired iOS games & Windows games, but I am unable to acquire data related to android games.
I have tried various documentations mentioned in this [link](http://www.pearltrees.com/bugmagnet/android-play-store-api/id8843559). But no use. Google is blocking most of them and others are not related to php.

Please suggest some latest working **PHP** API for extracting Google play store **GAMES**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out SerpApi. We handle proxies, solve captchas, and parse all the rich structured data for you.

With the API you can extract everything you see on the Google Play Store page, including all of the reviews as well.

Example PHP code for retrieving results from GAMES category (available in other libraries also):

```php
require 'path/to/google_search_results';

$query = [
  "api_key" => "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine" => "google_play",
  "hl" => "en",
  "store" => "apps",
  "gl" => "us",
  "apps_category" => "GAME"
];

$search = new GoogleSearch();
$results = $search->json($query);
```

Example JSON output:

```json
{
  "organic_results": [
    {
      "title": "Discover recommended games",
      "see_more_link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=ogoQCAESBEdBTUUqAggCUgIIAQ%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljJlEdM&gsr=ChOiChAIARIER0FNRSoCCAJSAggB:S:ANO1ljJdubc",
      "see_more_token": "ChOiChAIARIER0FNRSoCCAJSAggB:S:ANO1ljJdubc",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&see_more_token=ChOiChAIARIER0FNRSoCCAJSAggB%3AS%3AANO1ljJdubc&store=apps",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Roblox",
          "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roblox.client",
          "product_id": "com.roblox.client",
          "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&product_id=com.roblox.client&store=apps",
          "rating": 4.4,
          "extansion": {
            "name": "Roblox Corporation",
            "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5360036014478858866"
          },
          "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/OCDxsiIIxiZL6ZQYcO9Sixv6Vxl9z0avSkpd5kS6SAE_ZU_V7_rlzzA0hsesT0Z4hA=s50-rw",
          "images": [
            "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/sM1bmvALGL6yYh_UnXomtkIgO9IzoVSi5Jbo9SIPcv9p73jR5S1Xz1K-0VFZwpkcgQ=w330-h185-rw"
          ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "New & updated games",
      "see_more_link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=SjYKKgokcHJvbW90aW9uXzMwMDA3OTFfbmV3X3JlbGVhc2VzX2dhbWVzEEoYAxIER0FNRToCCAI%3D:S:ANO1ljJYK2k&gsr=CjhKNgoqCiRwcm9tb3Rpb25fMzAwMDc5MV9uZXdfcmVsZWFzZXNfZ2FtZXMQShgDEgRHQU1FOgIIAg%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljICr10",
      "see_more_token": "CjhKNgoqCiRwcm9tb3Rpb25fMzAwMDc5MV9uZXdfcmVsZWFzZXNfZ2FtZXMQShgDEgRHQU1FOgIIAg%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljICr10",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&see_more_token=CjhKNgoqCiRwcm9tb3Rpb25fMzAwMDc5MV9uZXdfcmVsZWFzZXNfZ2FtZXMQShgDEgRHQU1FOgIIAg%253D%253D%3AS%3AANO1ljICr10&store=apps",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Subway Surfers",
          "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiloo.subwaysurf",
          "product_id": "com.kiloo.subwaysurf",
          "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&product_id=com.kiloo.subwaysurf&store=apps",
          "rating": 4.6,
          "extansion": {
            "name": "SYBO Games",
            "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=7363891306616760846"
          },
          "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/N0cRWzreD-MT_IwcXKkK20Rzp10G1alWKGbw9McpfZ8Qa19SY-W3o0thOivS3BhZV4c=s50-rw",
          "images": [
            "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/i4h0nob9adP_bV7obHFJ0FSK2AwK2nGwSvml1Cudh0ni2U-Sb69wYuDzzCHFv6U3RX7T=w330-h185-rw"
          ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Pre-registration games",
      "subtitle": "Coming soon to Play",
      "see_more_link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=Sj0KMQorcHJvbW90aW9uXzMwMDAwMDBkNTFfcHJlX3JlZ2lzdHJhdGlvbl9nYW1lcxBKGAMSBEdBTUU6AggC:S:ANO1ljLVQMI&gsr=Cj9KPQoxCitwcm9tb3Rpb25fMzAwMDAwMGQ1MV9wcmVfcmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uX2dhbWVzEEoYAxIER0FNRToCCAI%3D:S:ANO1ljJICV4",
      "see_more_token": "Cj9KPQoxCitwcm9tb3Rpb25fMzAwMDAwMGQ1MV9wcmVfcmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uX2dhbWVzEEoYAxIER0FNRToCCAI%3D:S:ANO1ljJICV4",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&see_more_token=Cj9KPQoxCitwcm9tb3Rpb25fMzAwMDAwMGQ1MV9wcmVfcmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uX2dhbWVzEEoYAxIER0FNRToCCAI%253D%3AS%3AANO1ljJICV4&store=apps",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Diablo Immortal",
          "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blizzard.diablo.immortal",
          "product_id": "com.blizzard.diablo.immortal",
          "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&product_id=com.blizzard.diablo.immortal&store=apps",
          "extansion": {
            "name": "Blizzard Entertainment, Inc.",
            "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=8636572569301896616"
          },
          "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/8DtlOHx-zIncYJE-kwHnOTBXycjAzwufkuk0uad7_MzWP17auA24THldTwhEru-b-7I=s50-rw",
          "images": [
            "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IS3ExSTM5IskRgZQnF4RrTPUwh-D4TGlXdfahj33DGr-Y4CW55UpEeqyw6gazdpg-Q=w330-h185-rw"
          ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  },
  "serpapi_pagination": {
    "next": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?apps_category=GAME&engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&next_page_token=CsEBit_FqQO6AQgLENu_tbHXLxjbnqn8AxiCmMGOBRjprfD4Dhi_p5XjChij3diZBBjrr7AZGNzm9LsCGO3Y7eUCGMSuxcUFGKyKn6IJIIjZv3Iggf2anwEg_8m-igsgpY3k9gIggN_E5wsg6Kn7XyD_77mICiDe84i7AiDcu9vcCCDvosrNDyCGhuTFCyDKh_-IByDGsKfmCSCksMK5BSCQoczUBCDEoLO4CyDKm7-xCiC92tC9BSDl1tznASC-t4SMDBAK&store=apps",
    "next_page_token": "CsEBit_FqQO6AQgLENu_tbHXLxjbnqn8AxiCmMGOBRjprfD4Dhi_p5XjChij3diZBBjrr7AZGNzm9LsCGO3Y7eUCGMSuxcUFGKyKn6IJIIjZv3Iggf2anwEg_8m-igsgpY3k9gIggN_E5wsg6Kn7XyD_77mICiDe84i7AiDcu9vcCCDvosrNDyCGhuTFCyDKh_-IByDGsKfmCSCksMK5BSCQoczUBCDEoLO4CyDKm7-xCiC92tC9BSDl1tznASC-t4SMDBAK"
  }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-play-api) for more details.

Test the search live on the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&store=apps&apps_category=GAME).

---

You can also get specific game results.

Example PHP code for retrieving `Pokémon GO` results:

```php
require 'path/to/google_search_results';

$query = [
  "api_key" => "SECRET_API_KEY",
  "engine" => "google_play_product",
  "store" => "apps",
  "gl" => "us",
  "product_id" => "com.nianticlabs.pokemongo"
];

$search = new GoogleSearch();
$results = $search->json($query);
```

Example JSON output:

```json
{
  "product_info": {
    "title": "Pokémon GO",
    "editors_choice": {
      "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/editors_choice",
      "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/DGQjTn_Hp32i88g2YrbjrCwl0mqCPCzDjTwMkECh3wXyTv4y6zECR5VNbAH_At89jGgSJDQuSKsPSB-wVQ=s14-rw"
    },
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "Niantic, Inc.",
        "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Niantic,+Inc."
      }
    ],
    "categories": [
      {
        "name": "Adventure",
        "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME_ADVENTURE",
        "category_id": "GAME_ADVENTURE",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?apps_category=GAME_ADVENTURE&engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&store=apps"
      }
    ],
    "content_rating": {
      "text": "Everyone",
      "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IciOnDFecb5Xt50Q2jlcNC0LPI7LEGxNojroo-s3AozcyS-vDCwtq4fn7u3wZmRna8OewG9PBrWC-i7i=w56-h14-rw"
    },
    "rating": 4.3,
    "reviews": 14951022,
    "extansions": [
      "Offers in-app purchases"
    ],
    "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/jRKLgsCxR-jPnDBogDgx2Vj2MXy0_jBhhEcGJmmCjSnScUYabjSLEyAvnCmwmiNBXw=s180-rw",
    "offers": [
      {
        "text": "Install",
        "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&rdid=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&feature=md&offerId"
      }
    ],
    "description": "New! Now you can battle other Pokémon GO Trainers online! Try the GO Battle League today!Join Trainers across the globe who are discovering Pokémon as they explore the world around them. Pokémon GO is the global gaming sensation that has been downloaded over 1 billion times and named “Best Mobile Game” by the Game Developers Choice Awards and “Best App of the Year” by TechCrunch._______________Uncover the world of Pokémon: Explore and discover Pokémon wherever you are! Catch more Pokémon to complete your Pokédex! Journey alongside your Buddy Pokémon to help make your Pokémon stronger and earn rewards!Compete in epic Gym battles and...Team up with other Trainers to catch powerful Pokémon during Raid Battles! It’s time to get moving—your real-life adventures await! Let’s GO!_______________Notes: - This app is free-to-play and offers in-game purchases. It is optimized for smartphones, not tablets.- Compatible with Android devices that have 2GB RAM or more and have Android Version 6.0–10.0+ installed.- Compatibility is not guaranteed for devices without GPS capabilities or devices that are connected only to Wi-Fi networks.- Application may not run on certain devices even if they have compatible OS versions installed.- It is recommended to play while connected to a network in order to obtain accurate location information.- Compatibility information may be changed at any time.- Please visit PokemonGO.com for additional compatibility information. - Information current as of October 20, 2020.Read moreCollapse"
  },
  "media": {
    "video": {
      "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/KgDQ-Kjb2B7_jDP-8KmQDNhAmP2lqAV_w3zArOCBL7YZnQ02Qqp4VTlgdocO-4MFk4s=w720-h310-rw",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/DFXbVBFPOOs?ps=play&vq=large&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0"
    },
    "images": [
      "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/O-OR6Mh0AoNyiaYYaa3OJ_VHGfLqWW2qNzUUZxRRodD3fqs2Pm04FatavdNbz-jsMZM=w720-h310-rw",
      ...
    ]
  },
  "reviews": [
    {
      "title": "Aiden Cooper",
      "avatar": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhjS7nHA19xmSqgW_7T3ngu5zTjDO46K9ZF--l33A",
      "rating": 3,
      "snippet": "Game is fun but a lot of features don't work correctly. One important example of this is Adventure Sync. I enable it and accept permissions, and I log off hoping it track throughout the day. I log on again, and it's recorded nothing at all, and says it's on. Then I log in again another time and it says it's off. Please fix this, it's very difficult to hatch eggs.",
      "likes": 23,
      "date": "November 29, 2021"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "what_s_new": {
    "snippet": "Trainers, there’s always something new in Pokémon GO! - From ​​November 5, 2021, to November 14, 2021, celebrate light overcoming darkness with an all-new event, Festival of Lights!- Visual changes have been added to indicate when either your Pokémon storage or Item Bag is full. The center of the Poké Ball menu icon will turn orange when your Pokémon storage is full and revert to gray when storage space is made available."
  },
  "additional_information": {
    "updated": [
      {
        "snippet": "November 18, 2021"
      }
    ],
    "size": [
      {
        "snippet": "Varies with device"
      }
    ],
    "installs": [
      {
        "snippet": "100,000,000+"
      }
    ],
    "current_version": [
      {
        "snippet": "0.223.1"
      }
    ],
    "requires_android": [
      {
        "snippet": "6.0 and up"
      }
    ],
    "content_rating": [
      {
        "snippet": "EveryoneMild Fantasy ViolenceLearn more"
      },
      {
        "snippet": "EveryoneMild Fantasy ViolenceLearn more"
      },
      {
        "snippet": "Learn more",
        "link": "https://support.google.com/googleplay?p=appgame_ratings"
      }
    ],
    "interactive_elements": [
      {
        "snippet": "In-Game Purchases"
      }
    ],
    "in_app_products": [
      {
        "snippet": "$0.99 - $99.99 per item"
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      {
        "snippet": "View details"
      }
    ],
    "report": [
      {
        "snippet": "Flag as inappropriate",
        "link": "https://support.google.com/googleplay/?p=report_content"
      }
    ],
    "offered_by": [
      {
        "snippet": "Niantic, Inc."
      }
    ],
    "developer": [
      {
        "snippet": "Visit website",
        "link": "https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web"
      },
      {
        "snippet": "pokemon-go-support@nianticlabs.com",
        "link": "https://play.google.commailto:pokemon-go-support@nianticlabs.com"
      },
      {
        "snippet": "Privacy Policy",
        "link": "https://nianticlabs.com/privacy/pokemongo/en"
      },
      {
        "snippet": "Visit websitepokemon-go-support@nianticlabs.comPrivacy PolicyOne Ferry Building, Suite 200 San Francisco, CA 94111"
      }
    ]
  },
  "similar_results": [
    {
      "title": "Similar",
      "see_more_link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=ogonCBEqAggIMh8KGWNvbS5uaWFudGljbGFicy5wb2tlbW9uZ28QARgD:S:ANO1ljKcNx0&gsr=CiqiCicIESoCCAgyHwoZY29tLm5pYW50aWNsYWJzLnBva2Vtb25nbxABGAM%3D:S:ANO1ljLVe3w",
      "see_more_token": "CiqiCicIESoCCAgyHwoZY29tLm5pYW50aWNsYWJzLnBva2Vtb25nbxABGAM%3D:S:ANO1ljLVe3w",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&see_more_token=CiqiCicIESoCCAgyHwoZY29tLm5pYW50aWNsYWJzLnBva2Vtb25nbxABGAM%253D%3AS%3AANO1ljLVe3w&store=apps",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Slugterra: Slug it Out 2",
          "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dhxmedia.slugitout2",
          "product_id": "com.dhxmedia.slugitout2",
          "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&product_id=com.dhxmedia.slugitout2&store=apps",
          "description": "Pick up Greneater, Aquafreak, and Nightgeist in the Ghoul Slug Pack!",
          "rating": 4.7,
          "extansion": {
            "name": "Epic Story Interactive",
            "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5905438781451669270"
          },
          "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/PgphCA3N_CSH_mLekZ_0RHiXS7FOUSlZdaCIwmEGZ2Q7I4eJkJVvYSb6Q3Lt8YP3LPZf=s128-rw"
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "More by Niantic, Inc.",
      "see_more_link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=igM-ChkKEzc2MzI0NjkyNzI0MzEyMjQxMjkQCBgDEh8KGWNvbS5uaWFudGljbGFicy5wb2tlbW9uZ28QARgDGAE%3D:S:ANO1ljJ8G8M&gsr=CkGKAz4KGQoTNzYzMjQ2OTI3MjQzMTIyNDEyORAIGAMSHwoZY29tLm5pYW50aWNsYWJzLnBva2Vtb25nbxABGAMYAQ%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKQOY4",
      "see_more_token": "CkGKAz4KGQoTNzYzMjQ2OTI3MjQzMTIyNDEyORAIGAMSHwoZY29tLm5pYW50aWNsYWJzLnBva2Vtb25nbxABGAMYAQ%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKQOY4",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play&gl=us&hl=en&see_more_token=CkGKAz4KGQoTNzYzMjQ2OTI3MjQzMTIyNDEyORAIGAMSHwoZY29tLm5pYW50aWNsYWJzLnBva2Vtb25nbxABGAMYAQ%253D%253D%3AS%3AANO1ljKQOY4&store=apps",
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Pikmin Bloom",
          "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pikmin",
          "product_id": "com.nianticlabs.pikmin",
          "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_play_product&gl=us&hl=en&product_id=com.nianticlabs.pikmin&store=apps",
          "description": "Make every step count!",
          "rating": 3.6,
          "extansion": {
            "name": "Niantic, Inc.",
            "link": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Niantic,+Inc."
          },
          "thumbnail": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/lZhO5dn3aCCBkqfFBMCFQeTsCaCfKA_wdmXsco4HtZoy970MSPnXTSbm5Ub-Z3glHA=s128-rw"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-play-product-api) for more details.

Test the search live on the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_play_product&product_id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&gl=us&store=apps).

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*

Answer (score -1):

there is a api on [API](http://www.playstoreapi.com/),
i'm using that api to fetch app info from play store..
u have to pass only package name of app & your srcret key (this is generated when you register on that site)